# why code is blocked strange in this function

Tags: c++, gcc, operating-system

I'm writing a tiny system kernel follow this video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rnA6wpF0o4&list=PLHh55M_Kq4OApWScZyPl5HhgsTJS9MZ6M.
i meet a problem that doesn't emerge in the video: code just is blocked in getDriver function when PCI controller identify all devices

```cpp
//PCI controller function
void PeripheralComponentInterconnectController::selectDrivers(DriverManager* driver_manager,InterruptManager* interrupt_manager){
    // printf("{ void PeripheralComponentInterconnectController::selectDrivers\n");
    int function_num=0;
    for(int bus=0;bus<8;++bus){
        for(int device=0;device<32;++device){
            function_num=deviceHasFunction(bus,device) ? 8:1;
            for(int function=0;function<function_num;++function){
                PeripheralComponentInterconnectDeviceDescriptor dev= getDeviceDescriptor(bus,device,function);
                if(dev.vendor_id == 0 || dev.vendor_id == 0xFFFF){
                    continue;
                }
                for(int bar_num=0;bar_num<6;++bar_num){
                    BaseAddreeRegister bar = getBaseAddressRegister(bus,device,function,bar_num);
                    if(bar.addr && (bar.type == InputOutput))
                        dev.port_base = (uint32_t)bar.addr;
                }
// blocked in this getDriver
                Driver* driver = getDriver(dev, interrupt_manager);
                if(driver != 0){
                    driver_manager->AddDriver(driver);
                }
//end 
                printf("FOUND DEVICE:");
                printf("PCI BUS:");
                printfHex(bus & 0xFF);
                printf(",DEVICE:");
                printfHex(device & 0xFF );
                printf(", FUNCTION:");
                printfHex(function & 0xFF);
                printf(" = VENDOR_ID:");
                printfHex((dev.vendor_id & 0xFF00) >> 8);
                printfHex(dev.vendor_id & 0xFF);
                printf(",DEVICE_ID:");
                printfHex((dev.device_id & 0xFF00) >> 8);
                printfHex(dev.device_id & 0xFF);
                printf("\n");

            }
        }
    }

}

//getDriver function:

Driver*
PeripheralComponentInterconnectController::getDriver(PeripheralComponentInterconnectDeviceDescriptor dev,
InterruptManager* interrupt_manager){
   
    return 0; 
}
```

output:

[image]

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

you can see there are nothing in getDriver now ,but its still blocked in here.
I downloaded source code from the video and meet same problem.therefore,I'm sure it's my computer problem .

I thought it might have something to do with stacks(maybe stack overflow :),after that, I alter the parameter `PeripheralComponentInterconnectDeviceDescriptor dev` to`PeripheralComponentInterconnectDeviceDescriptor* dev`   so that reduce stack usage,and it work fine .

[image]

i try to add compile parameter  after that and alter back to `PeripheralComponentInterconnectDeviceDescriptor dev`.

```
-Wl,-z,stack-size=4194304
```

and enlarger the space that behind esp pointer so that avoid esp overwrite something,and it's blocked again :(.

have somebody tell me what happen?  Why isn't   blocked in code of video.thinks!

```
//makefile complie parameter
GCCPARAMS = -m32 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-leading-underscore -Wno-write-strings -fpermissive -fno-stack-protector -Iinclude
```

Comment: i'v solve this problem by add copy constructor for class "PeripheralComponentInterconnectDeviceDescriptor" ,but i still dont what happend,this problem maybe caused by runing in bare metal or something else,buz compiler will generally generate the copy constructor automately.